# Mapping a private member and populate it back with a method in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

With mongodb c# drivers we can map a private member like this

```
cm.MapField("_sessionTimes").SetElementName("SessionTimes");
```

And this populates SessionTimes in MongoDb.

This is a private member, it isn't a backing field of a public property.

Is there a way to populate this field back while getting the entity form MongoDb?

My class has AddSessionTime method, ideally I would like to use this method to populate that private field while mongodb drivers deserializing my entity.

By the way the type of _sessionTimes is

```
IDictionary<DayOfWeek, SessionTime>
```

SessionTime is a simple class:

```
public class SessionTime
{
    public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan End { get; set; }
}
```

And AddSessionTime is a method in my class:

```
public void AddSessionTime (DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, SessionTime sessionTime)
    {
        if (_sessionTimes.ContainsKey(dayOfWeek))
        {
            _sessionTimes[dayOfWeek] = sessionTime;
        }
        else
        {
            _sessionTimes.Add(dayOfWeek, sessionTime);    
        }
    }
```

Thanks.